# d/m/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

I want to change the data such as 9/4/2012(some cells with, green arrow in the right corner. ) into dd/mm/yyyy.

I want to standardize all the data of such column into dd/mm/yyyy , I format the columns as dd/mm/yyyy .

All data seem to appear displaying as dd/mm/yyyy. But issue cells , still having green arrow.

So I try to use DATE() function to format into date dd/mm/yyyy using DATE(MID(C13,5,4),MID(C13,3,1),MID(C13,1,1) for 9/4/2012 , but when converted appeared as 04/01/1906 (which is wrong).

PS: when I save as CSV, msg pop up like [test.csv may contain features that are not compatible with CSV. Do you want to keep the workbook  in this format? ]

If I can format all the cells into correct format, I can proceed with my formula TODAY()-D11 , Now I am hitting error because of incorrect format.

Comment: Try editing your question to make it more concise. The essence, if I understand it, is that the excel formatting of `DD/MM/YYYY` is not reflected in exported CSV files, which revert to `D/M/YYYY`.

Comment: already edited to ask my main point. Thanks. if data is correct, CSV format will be correct too.

Answer (score 2):

Select the column, go Data > Text to Columns > next > next > select the Date option and then select the DMY or MDY according to how the data is stored.

That will convert all dates stored as text to real dates which you can then format and use in calculations.

Comment: when I follow your advice, I set up as DMY.. but the value change to 04/09/2012 , Actually the real data is April 09,2012.

Comment: What are your regional settings? What is the default date format? You need to make sure that these are consistent with the computer settings and the Excel settings

Comment: Mine was in a date/time format so I used a Fixed width instead of Delimited on the first screen. Otherwise, all other steps were the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(ISTEXT(B2),DATE(RIGHT(B2,4),LEFT(B2,SEARCH("/",B2)-1),MID(B2,SEARCH("/",B2)+1,2)),DATEVALUE(TEXT(B2,"mm/dd/yyyy")))
```

And make sure to format the cells correctly (with dd/mm/yyyy).

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the dates you want to change. 
Hit "Ctrl" and the "1" key.
A pop-up box will open.
Select the "Number" tab and select "Custom" from the bottom of the list.
You will see two horizontal boxes: "Sample" and "Type"
The type box is in mm/dd/yyyy format. Retype the m's, d's, and y's in the format you wish. If you don't want slashes, replace those with something more to your personal tastes. Go nuts!